# Why doesn't Eclipselink 2.6 ship with workbench?

Tags: eclipselink, workbench

I'm in the middle of upgrading from eclipselink version 2.4.2 and version 2.6 for my company. The process has gone smoothly except for one detail: the workbench wasn't shipped with version 2.6 (yet it's in all previous versions).

First I'd like to know why.

Next, if I can't expect a workbench in version 2.6 and it was truly intended, I'd like to know what's recommended moving forward. Should I use the workbench in version 2.5.2 (this doesn't seem like the best option to me), or is there another utility which we should be using.

Extra Info: As far as I can see, this company favors the GUI approach to handle mappings over annotations. I just mention this so I don't *only* get answers that say "Obviously you should be using annotations. End." I'd appreciate answers that at least explore the possibility of using a GUI application.

I haven't been able to find any info on this, I hope someone can give some guidance or explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the rise in JPA and IDEs supporting JPA annotations/XML, JPA is now the prefered persistence api with the Workbench appearing inactive in favor of the Dali project in Eclipse.  While I can't find an official "it's been deprecated" message, the EclipseLink PM advises using the JPA interface here: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/2720577-104587406

As native projects will always be supported (the JPA methods are built on the native code), projects created from previous workbench versions will still work on the latest EclipseLink runtime, so there should not be any issues using the 2.5.2 Workbench version and then executing generated project classes/XML against EclipseLink 2.6.

Comment: Thank you Chris, this is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for.